# Objective-C: Show A window popup from background Cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have created a COCOA application that runs in user background and keeps on check for a notification.

When there is a notification then the application should display a popup window.

**How I am running the application in background?**

I have set *Application is background only*
[image]

Using the above method the application is getting launched but not getting shown and not visible in the dock.

**How I am showing popup**

```
    _popup =  [[showPopup alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"showPopup"];

    [self.window beginSheet:_popup.window  completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {}];

    //showing the window
    [_popup showWindow:self];
```

**Problem**

The popup is not getting shown. Please suggest what should I do...

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Instead of "Application is background only" (LSBackgroundOnly), you probably want "Application is agent (UIElement)" (LSUIElement).
- Make sure your window is hooked up to your window controller in the nib (it probably is, but just in case…)
- Don't forget to call

  `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];`

  to make sure your appliction comes into the foreground.

Comment: Many thanks for sparing your time on my question and I would like to inform you that when I am adding " LSBackgroundOnly" it is automatically getting changed to "Application is background only" and as you said I have added 
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]; after calling the window form. But not benefit the window is still not getting shown

Comment: You *don't* want LSBackgroundOnly. You want LSUIElement, instead. LSBackgroundOnly is for headless (i.e., UI-less) apps.

Comment: sir, its not working as well. May there is something worng in my understanding that's why I have created a dummy http://1drv.ms/1TRlf0R  In this dummy I am calling a form after 2 seconds of app finish launching. The issue is that the main form should not be shown but the second form should be shown which is getting called after 2 seconds

Comment: Make sure `LSUIElement` is set to `YES`! Also, uncheck "Visible at Launch" for your windows in Interface Builder. (Your project works for me, btw.)

Comment: please edit your answer so that it may help others as well. And tons and tons of thanks for helping me out of the problem.

Comment: Will do, when I'm at my computer again.